# Run PowerShell script with Windows service account from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, remote-server

I am trying to run a PowerShell script from server A318 on server F318 using a Task Scheduler job configured to run with a Windows service account, this service account has access to the destination path. Below is the command which is present in the script.

```cs
Get-ChildItem "\\F318\SFS\FileTransfer\" | Out-File "D:\Temp\SFS.txt"
```

The file SFS.txt is getting created with 0 byte on A318 "D:\Temp\SFS.txt" path.

Any correction that I need to make to the script?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem "\\F318\SFS\FileTransfer\" 2> "D:\Temp\sfs_err.txt" | Out-File ...`

Comment: Does the service account have access to the source path? Try running a PowerShell session on A318 'as' the service account, and execute the script. This will approximate the conditions when running as a task.